# Technology to use for creating an mobile app which can detect and track position of random objects in real time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, augmented-reality, vuforia

- I like to know which technology I can use for creating android application which has the feature of detecting an random object like hoarding board and after detecting, a video must played over that object. If the user move the camera , the video must also move over that object position.
- I have an example of what I want to achieve in this video of big burger https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhXW8_7CaHM . But I want to play that video on any type of hoarding the camera detect. Not only on specific trained object.
- I have study some technology like tensorflow and Vuforia which can made ar application.
- But I'm not sure if it can detect real time objects with tracking of the objects position.

Comment: I would think both detecting a random object real time and playing a video on the detected object could be a little too much for an android phone. But here's a machine learning framework I worked with that detected objects real time, maybe it can help you too, https://github.com/moorejee/Re3 .

Comment: I know OpenCV is a good solution for face recognition, might be of use as well (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088)

Comment: Even if it too much for android phones, still I want to give it a try. What I want is that if new objects get detect and they are in valid shapes ( as per our specification ) and  not have been trained before ( in machine learning ) , then also video must be played for that objects. So can we achieve it through the github repo you suggest ?

Comment: I think if we train a model for hoarding / poster/ movie tickets in tenserflow , then we can detect new hoarding boards and play a video on that detected part.

Comment: The repo I suggested works this way: you specify the initial objects bounding box locations (4 x, y values) and it updates these values each frame as the object or the camera moves, what's good about this framework is that it works on any object.But on a second thought this may not be that suitable for what you are trying to achieve. Maybe we should start by doing something very basic. Maybe try to play the video on a basic white paper, if it works you can move on to more complex issues like classification. However if you are not specific about using machine learning, qr code could work too.